# JSON datatype in forms with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Postgresql database table with JSON datatype.  Here is the Rails migration for this table:

```
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.references :athlete, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :competition, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :age_group, limit: 100
      t.text :tags, array: true, default: []
      t.json :results
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This table contains athlete's results from competitions and since different athletes can compete in different events I created the results field as JSON data type.

A sample entry for the results field would be:

```
{
  "event1": {
      "time":"10:00",
      "place":"2"
  },
  "event2": {
      "time":"1:25:00",
      "place":"1"
  }...
}
```

There are a finite number of events: a set of events for boy athletes, and a set of events for girl athletes, so I am trying to connect this field to a Rails form, with one section of the form for "boy" results and the other section for "girl" results.

Anyhow, I cannot seem to figure out the mechanism for getting Rails to understand the input or the output for use in the FormHelper.  I'm trying to do this with as little Javascript as possible.

Here are my strong parameters in my controller:

```
def result_params
  params[:result].permit(:age_group, :athlete_id, :competition_id, :results => {}, :tags => [])
end
```

I have tried to connect the form as such, but to no avail.

```
<%= f.fields_for :results do |res| %>
  <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Place</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%= res.fields_for :event1 do |e1| %>
    <tr>
      <td>Event 1</td>
      <td><%= e1.text_field :time %></td>
      <td><%= e1.text_field :place %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%= res.fields_for :event2 do |e2| %>
    <tr>
      <td>Event 2</td>
      <td><%= e2.text_field :time %></td>
      <td><%= e2.text_field :place %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    ...
```

It won't "get" the data from the @res.results automatically, I have to manually specify the value of each of those fields.  When I do that, that breaks my form from being used for new results.  Furthermore, when I fill the form out and press Submit, it submits correctly, but the value of my results field is converted to nil and I lose all my data.  I even tried to test something and just created a text area that I just typed a JSON object string and Rails just spit that out.  It's been pretty much trial and always error for a couple hours now... is what I'm trying to do even possible with Rails alone?

Comment: for the boy results vs girl results...instead of having two forms, why not just make :gender an attribute on the results table? Then you can loop through all the girl results when you want to @girl_results = Result.where(gender: 'female') or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Don't like naming a field on the results table results.

(2) I would restructure the data model for what you're trying to do. Keep it simple. It doesn't seem like you actually need to store Json in this case. The table is called results...why wouldn't there be a table entry for each result/event? An athlete has many results and a result belongs to a user. Each result would be an individual entry rather than trying to shove all the results into a hash. I'm sure you had a reason for wanting to do so but I can't think of the advantage. Having the has_many allows you to say @athlete.results and loop through them, which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: I originally created an EventResult model and linked to Result model, but it seemed like overkill, believe it or not. I thought a JSON object better represented the issue, since all of the event results are added/updated together, every time.  So you have a competition, and you update the "results" for that competition, the event results are just an attribute of the result. I have no issue querying the field, it's simply the storing and form pre-filling that I'm having issues with. I think if I had to update 6-8 event results every time I updated a result, I would run into just as many issues.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I feel like this is the correct answer.  I liked the flexibility of the JSON object but this way works admirably, for what I need it.